# C++ Write to a process with protected memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, c++-cli

So I decided to start getting into memory editing to be able to make more tools for a game. Seeings the game had patched the web version of the cheat by using cheat engine and or any other memory editing software out there, I decided to attempt to make a memory editing tool myself but with the use of NoxPlayer which is an android emulator as they have not patched the method on mobile but no one else knows the method.

Anyway, I came across this type of problem before with cheat engine itself with editing memory on Nox as the memory is most likely protected. But, with a few setting changes in cheat engine, I was then able to edit the memory inside the game on the emulator.

The thing is with my C++ application, it can read the memory from the addresses grabbed but it cannot write memory to the addresses.

**So I was wondering if someone could help me find a solution to be able to get passed the protected memory in the emulator to be able to change values?**

(Will also provide part of my current code below even though it may not be needed there).

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
        button1->Text = "Stop Spoofing";
        string ac;
        MarshalString(sid->Text, ac); // made a function to convert system string to std string
        stringstream stream(ac);
        stream >> value; // setting value to write to memory
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
        while (true)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker3->CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e->Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (DoesTxtExist())
                {
                    for (int i(0); i < address.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)address[i], &value, sizeof(value), 0);
                        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)address[i], &readTest, sizeof(int), 0);
                    }
                    label1->Text = L"Spoofing ID: "+readTest.ToString()+" "+value.ToString();
                    // was doing something like this to check if the values changed, but of course they didn't.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`VirtualProtectEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) to change the memory protection to writable before write attemps. Opening the handle with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS does not automatically render the entire process memory writable.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. Although I do feel like I might of done it wrong so i will provide a screenshot to you of my code so you could possibly help me out more. http://prntscr.com/mm6i3p/direct (or if that doesn't work: http://prntscr.com/mm6i3p)

Comment: What do these functions return? Did you check their error reports? Also, you do not need to call VirtualProtectEx() for each byte, it works on pages.

Comment: i dont see any errors to know of but basically still inside my program when it reads the data it is still the same, here is a screenshot of the program when active http://prntscr.com/mm6oqc. But again the value does not change for in game. Maybe Nox emulator is too well protected?

Answer (score 0):

You must run as administrator.  You may also require SeDebugPrivilege token privileges.

You can set your app to require administrator mode by using a manifest file.

You can set SeDebugPrivilege with this function from [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.adjusttokenprivileges)

```C#
Public Class AdjPriv()
{

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr
phtok);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name,
ref long pluid);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct TokPriv1Luid
{
    public int Count;
    public long Luid;
    public int Attr;
}

internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
internal const string SE_TIME_ZONE_NAMETEXT = "SeTimeZonePrivilege"; //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716(VS.85).aspx

private bool SetPriv()
{
    try
    {
    bool retVal;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_TIME_ZONE_NAMETEXT, ref tp.Luid);
    retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return retVal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw;
    return false;
    }

}
```

}

Once those two things are out of the way, if you're trying to overwrite anything that is code it will be in a code section of the module which will have execute permissions but not write permissions.

To get write permissions you must call VirtualProtectEx() on the memory location you wish to modify.  I don't have a C# snippet for this, but I basically have a wrapper for WriteProcessMemory which calls VirtualProtectEx() before and after that looks like this

```
void PatchEx(HANDLE hProc, char* dst, char* src, const intptr_t size)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProc, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, dst, src, size, nullptr);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProc, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```

You can re-create a C# pretty easily I would imagine.  Then anytime you want to write to memory, use this function to ensure the page memory protection constants are set correctly.